# How can I get rid of escaped character in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have the following string:

```
String s="create view robot_tests as \n" +
    "select number, alert, why,str_query from ( \n" +
    "SELECT count(*) AS number , \"ERROR\" AS alert, \"t01: a question doesnt have any rSAnswers\" AS why,\n" ;
```

Is there any easy way to just copy everything like a normal text? ie:

```
create view robot_tests as 
select number, alert, why,str_query from ( 
SELECT count(*) AS number , "ERROR" AS alert,
```

I usually just replace them manually <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> the `\n` and `\"` and concatenators, but it just takes a lot to remove each. I can't figure out how to ask Google (it just gives me Stack Overflow questions of people who need to replace/concatenate/remove slashes or escape characters)

Comment: have you tried source->format? ShiftLeft will move everything to the left until it hits the margin

Comment: it's not only indents, whole string is enclosed in quotes , quotes are escaped, new lines are also escaped, for every new line string is split and concatenated to the string on the next line. also other things are escaped like tabs, and of course sometimes I dont notice them and them problems...

Comment: Then use regex. Eclipse allows to do that I believe. Try them in the find/replace dialog. Instead of replacing one character at a time like you are doing group them (brackets and commas, I think will suffice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
Click inside string
Press alt+enter or click the light bulb
Click "Copy String concatenation text to the clipboard"
```